# How can I change the background image?

Tags: jquery, html, css

This sounds so easy to do and yet I can't seem to be able to do it. The idea is that when an 'a' tag is clicked, check if it has a class called 'collapsed'. If it does, change the 'ul' background (that the a tag is a part of). I don't know which 'a' tag was clicked so I don't know the id of the 'ul' that it is a part of... I thought I could drill up to find the parent 'ul' but it is not working.

HTML:

```
<ul class="some-class" id="some-id-1">  
   <a href="#" id="id-1">something</a>
   <li>  
      <a class="collapsed">something else</a>  
   </li>  
</ul>  

<ul class="some-class" id="some-id-2">  
   <a href="#" id="id-2">something</a>
   <li>  
      <a class="collapsed">something else</a>  
   </li>  
</ul>  

<ul class="some-class" id="some-id-3">  
   <a href="#" id="id-3">something</a>
   <li>  
      <a class="collapsed">something else</a>  
   </li>  
</ul>
```

my script:

```
$('a').click(function() {  
   var cName = this.className;  
   switch(cName) {
      case 'collapsed' :
         $(this).parent().find('> ul').css('background','url(img/red.png) 0 0');
      break;
   };
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Any and all suggestions are welcome...

Comment: JQuery is what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @Anonymous, That type of comment doesn't help anyone. If JQuery isn't the best solution then how about providing an alternate option?

Comment: I am simply suggesting that he use regular JavaScript to make his code more readable. That is all.

Comment: @Jason, THANK YOU. I don't think I need to say anymore, we're probably thinking the same thing... ;o)

Comment: @Anonymous That is called an answer and it belongs below with a detailed (constructive) example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using JQuery's [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) function this way -

```
$('a').click(function() {  
   var cName = $(this).attr('class');  
   if(cName == 'collapsed') {
        $(this).closest('ul').css('background','url(img/red.png) 0 0');
   };
});
```

Comment: YES! Genius! Works awesome! THANK YOU! :o)

Answer (score 0):

First thing, `this` should be used like `$(this)`.

```
$('a').click(function() {
   // Change the first .collapsed element next to the clicked a
   $(this).next('.collapsed').css('background-color', 'url(img/red.png) 0 0');
});
```